# Property of an element of $Pic^o(X)$ where $X$ is an abelian surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, intersection-theory, abelian-varieties

Let $X$ be an abelian surface and $L$ be a very ample line bundle on $X$. Let $M\in \textrm{Pic}^o\,X$. That is $T_x^*M\simeq M$ for all $x\in X$. We know that $H^i(X,M)=0$ for all $i$.

Is it true that $h^0(X,L) = h^0(X,L\otimes M)$? How do we prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you are looking for is true. It comes from two facts.

First, the Euler characteristic is a numerical invariant. Thus, if you twist $L$ by a numerically trivial line bundle $M$, you get the same Euler characteristic. You can see this form Riemann-Roch for surfaces: since $M$ is numerically trivial, intersection product with $L$ or $L\otimes M$ are the same.

Also, if you twist an ample line bundle $L$ by a numerically trivial line bundle $M$, $L \otimes M$ is still ample. See Kleiman's criterion for ampleness about this.

Second, for an ample line bundle $H$ on an abelian variety, we have $\chi (H)=h^0(H)$. This follows from a more general result about abelian varieties, which says that if a line bundle $L$ is non-degenerate (i.e. $\chi(L) \neq 0$), then all the cohomologies but one vanish. As for reference, see for instance Mumford's book "Abelian Varieties", under the section "Cohomology of Line Bundles".

These two facts give you the claim. Also, note that we just need $L$ ample, not very ample.

Comment: ! Thanks. How do we see that $M$ in $Pic^oX$ is numerically trivial? Is it obvious?

Comment: One way to address the question is to say "by definition". For a projective variety $X$, the scheme $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ parametrizing line bundles on $X$ has several components. We denote by $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ the connected component to the identity $\mathcal{O}_X$. On $X \times \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ there is a universal line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ (the Poincaré one in the case of abelian varieties) such that $\mathcal{L}|_{X \times \lbrace y \rbrace} \cong L_y$, where $L_y$ is the element of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ labelled by $y$. So, you can deform elements of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ one into another.

Comment: It is a heuristic way to explain why we expect elements of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ not to affect the intersection product, since you can topologically deform them into $\mathcal{O}_X$.. What I said is not very formal! A formal answer goes into looking how you define your intersection product, and how you identify the class of line bundles that are irrelevant for it. It is another way to define $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$; then, you have to show that the two definitions I gave agree. If you want to read about the intersection product for surfaces, you could look at Beauville's "Complex Algebraic Surfaces".